# Partitioning Software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I used to use Patition Magic Pro from Norton to do disk partitioning.

Now that I have Windows 7, I have been warned, by the OS itself and later confirmed on the internet, that Partition Magic Pro has compatibility issues with Windows 7.

So, I am asking you which software partitioning software do you recommend. It would be great if it was freeware but I know it is hard to find a good parititioning app that's free, so, if you know a good one that's paid, there's no problem and please mention it in your reply.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am aware of "create and format disk partitions feature" of Windows 7, but that's not enough for me. I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 bits.

Comment: I used the Storage module in the control panel -> computer administration, along with gparted. Both worked fine. What is is that you want to do that can't be handled by the in built partition software ?

Comment: I want to extend my C: drive, but the "extend volume" option isn't available. I suppose that's because it is some kind of special parition since it contains the OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My choice would be:

[MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) -   Freeware.

Other alternatives are:

[Paragon Partition Manager Personal](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-personal/release.html) -  Not free but there is an offer on now and its reduced by quite a bit.

or

[Acronis Partition Manager](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/partitioning.html) -  Also not free.

If you want a bootable CD to perform partitioning tasks, these are a couple of options:

[Partition Wizard Bootable CD](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html)

or

[gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The New Acronis Disk Director 11 is out.
.
http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/

Comment: @Moab: Or rather, [this one](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/diskdirector-workstation/) -- it has more features.

Comment: @Pulse: There *is* [a free version of Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/)!

Comment: @Mehrdad too expensive for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've used:
EASEUS Partition Master 6.0.1 - Best Free Magic Partition Manager
http://www.partition-tool.com/
It's free and it works

Comment: Free version only works with 32 bit :)