# Free software for create partition (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partitioning Software for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/159879/partitioning-software-for-windows-7)

Is there a free software that make me able to create a partition on my Desktop?

I have Windows 7 64bit