# Looking for a free partition manager

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partitioning Software for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/159879/partitioning-software-for-windows-7)

Hi.  I'm preparing to attempt to triple-boot my computer and before I start, I'll need to change some stuff around on my hard drive.  So, I'm looking for a good, free partition manager.  Anybody know of one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) is great. Especially handy is the [Gparted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) as you can boot into it from a CD/USB key.