# disk partition issue in XP

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, disk-utility

How to partition disk dynamically on Windows XP SP3 (32-bit)? Currently, I only have one drive C, and I want to divide it into Drive C, Drive D and Drive E without data lost.

Comment: You could also find something useful from this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/159879/partitioning-software-for-windows-7/159883#159883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred method (for XP, 7 enables you to shrink/create partitions dynamically) is to boot into Ubuntu using a Live CD, and then use the [Gparted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) Utility to shrink the primary partition and create the others.

EDIT: GParted is apparently avaible as a stand-alone live CD but I have only used it as part of Ubuntu.

Comment: Any Windows based utilities? I am not familiar with Ubuntu, and want to avoid mistake to destroy data.

Comment: Gparted is designed for ease-of-use but nevertheless try Partition Magic: http://partedmagic.com/doku.php.

Comment: Also, if you are afraid of destroying data, that means you aren't backing up! The hard drive could fail at any time. Might want to think about backing up. External HDs are cheap! Don't risk it. :)